# InfoPath 2010 Add Field or Group Shortcut Key

Tags: infopath

Is there a shortcut key for InfoPath 2010 Designer to bring up the "Add Field or Group" dialog box?

Comment: Which dialog box do you mean? I cannot find "Add field or Group" anywhere. All you can do in Infopath 2010 is add sections (do you mean this by "group" or you can add different controls ("fields"?) one of these controls is the Person/Group Picker.

Answer (score -1):

Use the **insert** key. You have to make sure the Data Source task pane is highlighted (**Alt-N** and then select Data Source or just **F6** if it is already visible but just not selected). Highlight any folder (not field) in the list and hit **insert**.